# CollapsingToolbarLayout cannot be instantiated

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to implement a CollapsingToolbarLayout in my app (I want it to be like play store's parallax effect)

I have seen many questions on stackOverflow itself as well as Android's developer site.

The problem is, I always get an error in the IDE (Android Studio)

`The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout`

If I run the activity on my phone anyway, the app crashes with error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method setLayoutDirection(Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;I)V in class Landroid/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat' appears in /data/data/com.hemal.eventhub2/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-v4-24.0.0_b8d850cc5f06d621d9211f2cbc20e32dfc36ae82-classes.dex)
                                                                       at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.setStatusBarScrim(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:663)
```

I am pretty sure this has something to do with conflicting imports or dependencies.

My app module gradle script is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hemal.eventhub2"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Following are some of the imports in my app's MainAcitivity

```
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

Are the above imports or dependencies conflicting which are causing the trouble.
I have also updated my Android Studio to 2.2.1 from 1.5.1 hoping it might solve the problem

Can you please guide me which SDKs, imports and dependencies I should remove, keep or download to get the CollapingToolbarLayout work.

Comment: Your target SDK is 21. Your min SDK is 19. But yet, you've compiled libraries for SDK 23. Then, the error refers to `com.android.support-support-v4-24.0.0` (SDK 24). So, yes, probably a dependency problem, but it's hard to identify which one you need.

Comment: And this issue was posted here. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211108

Comment: So I have SDKs for API 19, 21,23 installed and I set my minSDK as 19 while creating the project and target at 21. Should I change the target or min SDK version or start a new project from scratch and add the source files to it hoping that it might work? I have spent about 4 hours behind this now.

Comment: You really only need the SDK for the `compileSdkVersion` installed. According to that issue I posted, upgrading Android Studio seemed to break it. You could try disabling Instant Run, but I am not sure if that fixes it.